# Building m2crypto: 7 unresolved externals

Tags: build, openssl, windows-7-x64, python-3.3, m2crypto

I've tried to build [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) ([github](https://github.com/ametaireau/M2Crypto)) for win-amd64-py3.3:

```
python setup.py build --compiler msvc
```

And I've got an linker's unresolved external symbol errors ([full log](https://gist.github.com/kbec/5495302#file-m2crypto-build-log)):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:D:\Programy\Python33\libs /LIBPATH:D:\Programy\Python33\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\pkg\lib ssleay32.lib libeay32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit___m2crypto build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.3\M2Crypto\__m2crypto.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\SWIG\__m2crypto.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\SWIG\__m2crypto.pyd.manifest
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit___m2crypto' specified multiple times; using first specification
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\SWIG\__m2crypto.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\SWIG\__m2crypto.exp
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyString_AsStringAndSize referenced in function m2_PyString_AsStringAndSizeInt
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyString_FromStringAndSize referenced in function bn_to_mpi
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyInt_AS_LONG referenced in function asn1_integer_set
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyBuffer_New referenced in function ec_key_get_public_der
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyFile_AsFile referenced in function _wrap_err_print_errors_fp
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyFile_Check referenced in function _wrap_err_print_errors_fp
_m2crypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PyInstance_New referenced in function ssl_verify_callback
build\lib.win-amd64-3.3\M2Crypto\__m2crypto.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

What's going on? I'm using [Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1e](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Do I need older libraries?

Answer (score 0):

from the full log it looks like one first problem is that the compiler can't find the python c header files. Then the linker can't find the python library. Perhaps the options to cl.exe are not good (shouldn't it be `/ID:\...` instead of `-ID:\...`?) or you don't have the python header files installed.